# How effective is the Graston Technique® to treat a tendinopathy?

Tags: tendinopathy, tendons, physiotherapy

How effective is the Graston Technique® to treat a tendinopathy?

I am mostly interested in epicondylopathies (medial or lateral, i.e., tennis elbows and golfer elbows)

---

What I have found so far:

I read on http://www.grastontechnique.com/home:

> Since 1994, Graston Technique® (GT) has been the leading modality in Instrument-Assisted Soft Tissue Mobilization (IASTM). GT enables clinicians to effectively address scar tissue and fascial restrictions and maintain optimal range of motion in their patients through comprehensive training and education. **GT is clinically proven to achieve faster and better outcomes for acute and chronic conditions such as Achilles Tendonitis**, Carpal Tunnel, Adhesive Capsulitis, IT Band Syndrome, Lumbar Strain and Plantar Fasciitis.

http://www.grastontechnique.com/clinical-trials lists the following clinical trials:

- Heinecke ML, Thuesen ST, Stow RC (2014). Graston Technique on shoulder motion in overhead athletes (.pdf). Journal of undergraduate kinesiology research, 10(1), 27-39. http://www.grastontechnique.com/docs/research/gt_on_shoulder_motion.pdf
- Laudner K, Compton BD, McLoda TA, Walters CM (2014). Acute effects of instrument assisted soft tissue mobilization for improving posterior shoulder range of motion in collegiate baseball players. International journal of sports physical therapy, 9(1), 1-7. http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3924602/
- Garrett TR, Neibert PJ (2014). Effect of Graston Technique as a treatment for patients with chronic plantar fasciosis: a randomized controlled trial (.pdf). Journal of athletic training, 49(3), S57-58 http://natajournals.org/doi/pdf/10.4085/1062-6050-49.3.s1#page=57
- Toepper BW, Docherty CL, Donahue M, Kingma J, Schrader J (2013). The effects of the Graston Technique on knee extension angle (.pdf). Journal of athletic training, 48(3), S128. http://natajournals.org/doi/pdf/10.4085/1062-6050-49.3.s1#page=57
- Schaefer JL, Sandrey MA (2012). Effects of a 4-week dynamic-balance-training program supplemented with Graston instrument assisted soft-tissue mobilization for chronic ankle instability (.pdf). Journal of sport rehabilitation, 21(4), 313-326. http://natajournals.org/doi/pdf/10.4085/1062-6050-48.3.s1#page=129
- Heyer K, Docherty C, Donahue M, Schrader JW (2012). Effect of implement assisted soft tissue mobilization techniques on iliotibial band tightness (.pdf). Journal of athletic training, 47(3), S128. http://natajournals.org/doi/pdf/10.4085/1062-6050-47.3.s1#page=128
- Vardiman JP, Horinek RJ, McCartney MK, Graham ZA, Moodie NJ, Gallagher PM (2012). The ability of instrument assisted soft tissue mobilization to attenuate inflammation and symptoms of muscle damage after an eccentric exercise protocol (.pdf). Journal of athletic training, 47(3), S142. http://natajournals.org/doi/pdf/10.4085/1062-6050-47.3.s1#page=142

But I couldn't find any randomized controlled trials or - ideally - systematic reviews on the effectiveness of Graston Technique® to treat a tendinopathy.

I emailed info@grastontechnique.com the following (the contact form on http://www.grastontechnique.com/contact doesn't work):

> Hi,
>
> The front page of your website claims that "Graston Technique is
>   clinically proven to achieve faster and better outcomes for acute and
>   chronic conditions such as Achilles Tendonitis".
>
> Is there any randomized controlled trials or - ideally - systematic
>   reviews on the effectiveness of Graston Technique® to treat a
>   tendinopathy? (I am mostly interested in epicondylopathies, medial or
>   lateral, i.e., tennis elbows and golfer elbows)
>
> Thanks, 
> Franck